# Телеграм бот на python - проблема с answerCallbackQuery

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Проблема с answerCallbackQuery

Вот фрагмент кода:

```
        #show alert
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.message.chat.id, show_alert=False, text="test alert")
```

Консоль:

**ApiTelegramException('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: query is too old and response timeout expired or query ID is invalid')**

Запрос точно не "too old" и ID должно считывать верное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не call.message.chat.id а call.id

```
bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id = call.id, text = 'This is a test', show_alert = True)
```